# How to Repair Corrupt System Files from a Installation Disc OR Manual

Tags: windows-8.1, 64-bit, dism, sfc

I'm using Windows 8.1 x64, build 6.3.9600.17031, using the Command Prompt with administrator privileges.

```
sfc /scannow
```

returns:

```
...found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them.
```

and

```
dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
```

returns:

```
Error: 0x800f0906
The source files could not be downloaded.
```

(and the Windows Update Service is not able to start because those files are missing.)

also tried

```
dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth /source:wim:F:\sources\install.wim:1 /limitaccess
```

and returned:

```
Version: 6.3.9600.17031
Image Version: 6.3.9600.16384
Error: 0x800f081f
The source files could not be found.
```

I mounted the image, and tried from there.

```
dism /mount-image /imagefile:F:\sources\install.wim /index:1 /mountdir:C:\offline

dism /online /cleanup-image /restoreHealth /source:c:\offline /limitaccess
```

also returning:

```
Error: 0x800f081f
```

So i Filtered the details of `CBS.log` to `sfc.txt` with below code,

```
findstr /i /c:"[SR]" "%windir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log" | findstr /i /v /c:"verify" > "%userprofile%\Desktop\sfc.txt"
```

and filtered log is :

```
2015-04-13 17:07:53, Info                  CSI    0000004b [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:30{15}]"ISymWrapper.dll" of ISymWrapper, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope neutral, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:b03f5f7f11d50a3a}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2015-04-13 17:07:58, Info                  CSI    0000004d [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:30{15}]"ISymWrapper.dll" of ISymWrapper, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope neutral, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:b03f5f7f11d50a3a}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2015-04-13 17:07:58, Info                  CSI    0000004e [SR] This component was referenced by [l:162{81}]"Microsoft-Windows-NetFx2-OC-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.9600.16384.NetFx2"
2015-04-13 17:07:58, Info                  CSI    00000051 [SR] Could not reproject corrupted file [ml:520{260},l:102{51}]"\??\C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727"\[l:30{15}]"ISymWrapper.dll"; source file in store is also corrupted
2015-04-13 17:09:27, Info                  CSI    0000005c [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:20{10}]"uireng.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Compatibility-UI-Recording, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2015-04-13 17:09:41, Info                  CSI    00000061 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:20{10}]"uireng.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Compatibility-UI-Recording, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2015-04-13 17:09:41, Info                  CSI    00000062 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:330{165}]"Microsoft-Windows-Client-Features-Package-AutoMerged-base~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.9600.16384.Microsoft-Windows-Client-Features-Package-AutoMerged-base-Deployment"
2015-04-13 17:09:41, Info                  CSI    00000065 [SR] Could not reproject corrupted file [ml:520{260},l:46{23}]"\??\C:\WINDOWS\System32"\[l:20{10}]"uireng.dll"; source file in store is also corrupted
2015-04-13 17:10:05, Info                  CSI    00000087 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"chs_boot.ttf" of Microsoft-Windows-BootEnvironment-Core-Fonts-CHS-Boot, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2015-04-13 17:10:05, Info                  CSI    00000089 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"jpn_boot.ttf" of Microsoft-Windows-BootEnvironment-Core-Fonts-JPN-Boot, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2015-04-13 17:10:10, Info                  CSI    0000008b [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"jpn_boot.ttf" of Microsoft-Windows-BootEnvironment-Core-Fonts-JPN-Boot, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2015-04-13 17:10:10, Info                  CSI    0000008c [SR] This component was referenced by [l:350{175}]"Microsoft-Windows-Client-Features-Package-AutoMerged-minkernel~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.9600.16384.Microsoft-Windows-Client-Features-Package-AutoMerged-minkernel-Deployment"
```

in the end of thats is `Hash Mismatch`

How do I repair the Corrupt System Files?

Can I tell DISM to use the Windows installation disc as the source?

Comment: Hash mismatch? Any chance you used the wrong disc by mistake?

Comment: You might download and reinstall some of the files; e.g. "ISymWrapper.dll's description is "Microsoft .NET Runtime Managed Symbol Wrappers" for .NET. You can download any .NET installation (there appears to be only one version of ISymWrapper.dll).

Comment: 3 of the files are fonts if they are unused they don't need to be repaired.  Another 2 are not part of WinSXS so they can repaired by installing again. You should uninstall the 2.0 .NET Framework

Comment: try an older 8.1 RTM ISO if the April or December 2014 ISOs don't work.

Comment: i installed win8.1 AIO x64 Mar2014, and not updated that

Comment: 6.3.9600.17031 shows me that you use at least the April 2014 ISO